# Is there a way that I can search the Google Places API to find unclaimed businesses?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places, google-my-business-api

I would like to use the Google Places API to search businesses that are unclaimed in specific areas. I think this would be a cool project. Is there another way to do this perhaps by scraping? I have been trying for weeks and I cannot seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

There is no intention to make owner details available at the API, as that would be a honeypot for spammers. More details on the feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35819976

Comment: I don't need the owner details. I just need to get the businesses from an area and sort the ones that are unclaimed

Comment: unclaimed it means the owner details are not set, so it's the same thing.